# How to match on non-existing key of map in function head

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

I have a function that maintains some values as state for its recursion and in order to be flexible with the order of its arguments, I am using a `Map` to store the state and pass it around between calls.

My base case is that the function gets called without a `socket`, so there should be a case where only that setup is done. However, I can't find a way to match a non-existing key of a `Map`.

Attempts:

```
def measure(args = %{socket: nil}) ...

def measure(args = %{socket: socket}) when not is_port(socket) ...
```

However, these patterns only match when there **exists** a key `socket` that is `nil`/not a port.

Is there a way of specifying a pattern that does match a non-existing key? Or do I have to create another *entry* function that provides default values for my Map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a clause that matches on any value for that and add another one after:

```
def measure(args = %{socket: socket}) do
  handle_socket(socket, args)
end

def measure(args) do
  handle_without_socket(args)
end
```

Generally speaking, the preferred way of using maps is via the strict syntax. You would just match on `:socket` or call `args.socket` and it will fail if a socket is not available as key.

If you are passing optional data, maybe you want to use a keyword list instead of a map.

Comment: Thanks so far! Can you give me a short example of using the strict syntax in the function head? Like, how would the first definition in your post look that way?

Comment: The strict syntax is exactly what I wrote above without the fallback clause. You are matching on the key and that is it. Use `map.field` outside of patterns/guards.

Answer (score 8):

With Elixir version 1.10.0 there is a new guard intruduced called `is_map_key` (https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#is_map_key/2)

You can now handle non existing keys in maps like:

```
def measure(args) when not is_map_key(args, :socket) do
  handle_without_socket(args)
end

def measure(args = %{socket: socket}) do
  handle_socket(socket, args)
end
```